# React Native multiple inputs

Tags: react-native

I am actually making an app for a little job, that consists in taking 3 dates, and calclating multiple other dates from those 3. These are supposed to be dates for routine checks, etc...
I have hit a problem though : I can't find how to handle multiple inputs. I have 3 DatePickers, that look like this :

```
<DatePicker
    dateMes={this.state.dateMes}
    mode="date"
    placeholder="select date"
    format="DD-MM-YYYY"
    minDate="01-01-1950"
    maxDate="01-01-2050"
    androidMode="spinner"
    showIcon={false}
    onDateChange={this.onDateChange}
/>
```

With the only thing changing is dateMes (becoming dateInit and dateLast).
To initiate those i have :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { dateMes: "01-01-2000" }
    this.state = { dateLast: "01-01-2000"}
    this.state = { dateInit: "01-01-2000" }
}
```

I am kind of a noob, so it may be a basic problem.
My question is : what do i have to change, and what names do i have to change to have 3 different input to work with.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add this function :

```
onDateChange = (state) => (event,value) => {
  this.setState({
    [state]:value
  });
}
```

and change your code from :

```
onDateChange={this.onDateChange}
```

to :

```
onDateChange={this.onDateChange('your state name'}
```

for example :

```
onDateChange={this.onDateChange('dateMes')}
```

Maybe can help you :)
Note: you can change your constructor method to this :

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = { 
    dateMes: "01-01-2000",
    dateLast: "01-01-2000",
    dateInit: "01-01-2000"
  }
}
```

i think it's better, good luck :)

Comment: I tested that. I'm getting 
    
"Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: name" and then a lots of URLs.

Comment: sorry for that, can you change `[state]:name` into `[state]:value` ?